# New thread uses the same connection as main thread in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I run the below code in a Rails console:

```
User.count
Thread.new { User.count; puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.connection.object_id }.join
puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.object_id
```

As I expected I get two different connection objects:

```
46981836802520
46981834013480
```

When I put the same code into my minitest test case I get the same connection twice.

Do you know why? Is it some minitest configuration?

Comment: Are you using the database_cleaner gem?

Comment: Another question - what's your pool size in the test env?

Comment: Nope, don't use this gem and my connection pool in the test env is 10

Answer (score 1):

I think [this is the PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28083) that introduced this behavior

> This change uses the statement cache to lock the threads to using a
> single connection ID instead of each not being able to see each other.
> This code only runs in the fixture setup and teardown so it does not
> affect real production databases.

Answer (score 0):

It appears only one ActiveRecord connection is allowed in multiple threads.

Check with:

`active_record_intialize unless ActiveRecord::Base.connected?`

... Where active_record_initialize is a method that calls ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection.

It's not perfect, but it seems to be more reliable with lots of threads.